# How to implement moment.js as a pipe in an Angular2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I would like to implement moment.js library inside an angular2 project i order to convert a `UTC` time to a certain time zone `Europe/london` and that using `moment` and `[moment timezone]` [1](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

So far, I have installed `moment.js` in my Angular2 project using the following command:

> npm install moment --save

Here is my current code:

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'moment' })
class MomentPipe{
  transform(date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
}
```

The Html:

I received the time from the backend as an object

```
//time.bookingTime.iso == 2016-07-20T21:00:00.000Z

 {{time.bookingTime.iso | moment}}
```

It didn't work for me and I think that I have wrong implementation

Answer (score 28):

***Update: June 2018***

Official Documentation about [***PIPES***](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

To learn about [*Moment in Typescript*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) and [*Moment Date Formats*](https://momentjs.com/).

Example given below based on the Question here! Using `PIPE` technique we can use moment in Angular View as well (*Date Formatting*).

**MomentPipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({ name: 'dateFormat' })
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Date | moment.Moment, dateFormat: string): any {
        return moment(value).format(dateFormat);
    }
}
```

**You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MomentPipe } from './momentPipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Your Modules
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // Your Components
    MomentPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    // Your Providers
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Use it in your View/Html like below.,***

```
{{ createdDate | dateFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}
```

Hope this helps.,

Comment: Works very well after `npm install moment --save`, thank you @RajeshKdev.

Comment: You are Welcome, Glad that helped you!!

Comment: Also with null and async

transform(value: Date | moment.Moment | null, dateFormat: string = 'YYYY-MM-DD'): string {
    return moment(value).format(dateFormat);
  }

{{ createdDate | async | dateFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}

Answer (score 18):

When you need to use it, you have to specify it in the @component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './xyz.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.css'],
    pipes: [MomentPipe],
    directives: [...]
})
public export ...
```

and use it in the html in this way:

```
{{now | momentPipe:'YYYY-MM-DD'}}
```

btw, this is my way to write the pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
    name: 'momentPipe'
})
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Date|moment.Moment, ...args: any[]): any {
        let [format] = args;
        return moment(value).format(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: When changing the variable passed in to the pipe (in your case, `now`), I found that the pipe wasn't executed, presumably because the change isn't a _pure change_. I used `@Pipe({ name: 'momentPipe', pure: false })` to make this an impure pipe which fixed this problem.

Comment: This wont work unless the string you passed will be enclosed in square brackets. i.e the line should be modified as - {{now | momentPipe:['YYYY-MM-DD']}}
This is because argument received by pipe has data type array of type any.

Comment: @Niraj The typescript code uses Spread Operator (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html). This operator converts the list of parameters to an array. So it is wrong to to send an array to the transform function.

Comment: @Sierrodc but i am sending array and only then its working. Otherwise its no taking the rest of the argument. ex - if i pass "DD-MM-YYYY", the output will be current day i.e 22 only and not in the entire format.

Comment: @Niraj I don't know your implementatino but, If I write something like momentPipe:'YYYY-MM-DD':'something':'else' in the template, then in typescript I have args = ['YYYY-MM-DD':'something':'else']. 
I don't know why you need to specify square brakets. Which browser are you using? typescript version? angular version?

Comment: Important thing (at least for ionic): to import a pipe, now need to add it to `@NgModule`, to `declarations` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
}
}
```

Comment: It's the exact same thing that I am having, except your code is for TypeScript not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngx-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment) - it's an excellent `moment.js` wrapper, designed for Angular 2+.

It can do pretty much anything you need out-of-the-box, and in your case:

```
 {{time.bookingTime.iso | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}
```