# How to format the date 19990813 (YYYY-MM-DD) to 13.08.1999 (DD-MM-YYYY) with the the dots?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

I have problem to convert the date 19990813 of type string given by the backend to 13.08.1999 with the dots. I am not able to do so..

Using Angulars in-build date-format-function I got always the wrong date.

How can I achieve my goal?

I am thankful for any advice.

Kind regards

Anna Marie

Comment: Do you want it to be a pipe operator? That is preferred if you're using it in a template.

Comment: What if i tell you that *the date 19990813 (YYYY-MM-DD)* is actually of format `YYYYmmDD` ??

Comment: If it is preferred, I would like to use it :). I have to search a little bit. Thanks for the advice

Comment: yes, @AnnaMarie, for performance reasons you should definitely use the pipe operator. I will post the code for it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, I wanted it to be a little bit more clearly shown, but you are may right :)

Comment: But it you think about it, if that is `YYYYmmDD` then `DD.mm.YYYY` is what you want. so `| date :"DD.mm.YYYY"`

Comment: @Antoniossss I believe  it would be a problem using the default date pipe, had it been `YYYY-MM-DD` then something like this could had worked: `{{"1999-08-13" | date: "dd.MM.yyyy"}}`

Comment: Moment pipe is here but you would need to put `pipes` in `app.module` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490410/how-to-implement-moment-js-as-a-pipe-in-an-angular2-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: There are literally hundreds of duplicates of this question. Maybe try google next time?

Answer (score 4):

You can install `npm i moment` and use like this

```
datestring = '19990813';
  constructor(){
     let date = moment(this.datestring, 'YYYYMMDD');
     let datedot = date.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
     alert(datedot);
  }
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-js-format

Comment: Similarly moment pipe is here but you would need to put pipes in app.module https://stackoverflow.com/a/38491960/4711754

Comment: yes, if you need use this format in other file, you should create a custom pipe for it

Comment: I really can't see the need for a date library to reformat a string that requires a single expression. You can also post the code here as a runnable snippet.

Comment: i suggest momentjs because may be they need more format in real project

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this.

```js
let date = `19990813`

let regex = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/

let newDate = date.replace(regex, "$3.$2.$1")
console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: Or just `date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/, "$3.$2.$1")`. :-)

Comment: @RobG yeah, but I feel it's good to do it date libraries as suggested in another answer. They would be optimized and tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this string transformation in a component's template, the best choice (for performance reasons) is to use a pipe operator.

Use the solution proposed by xyz for the string transformation itself.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDateFormat'
})
export class MyDateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
        if (!value) {
            return value;
        } else {
            // process the 'value' param and return its result according to xyz's solution
        }
    }
}
```

then in your template, use it like this:

```
inputDate | myDateFormat
```

where inputDate is '19990813'.

And don't forget to import this class to the angular module that will use it.