# Is there a way to get the formatted date output with Angular Pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, date-formatting

I have a ISO Zone Date Time String which looks something like `'2020-01-15T10:45:20+02:30[US/Denver]'`. I am trying to get an angular pipe to make this look something like `'15 Jan 2020 ( US/Denver )'`. What would be the best way to do this.

Currently I do not have a proper pipe implementation on this and this is how I have achieved the expected output

```
{{ dateInput | date:"dd-MMM-yyyy" }}{{ someFuntionThatReturnsTimeZoneWithStringManipulation() }}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had success with creating a pipe that wraps the moment.js library in the past, see for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490410/how-to-implement-moment-js-as-a-pipe-in-an-angular2-project (Angular 2, might need slight tweaks to get it to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the default date pipe, split the string, transform the date and return back the combined string.

Here is a quick implementation

Pipe

```js
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateLocation',
  pure: true
})
export class DateLocationPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale);
  }

  transform(value: any, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): any {
    const date = value.split('[');
    return super.transform(date[0], format, timezone, locale) + ' (' + date[1].replace(/\]/g, ')');
  }
}
```

Component template

```js
{{ dateInput | dateLocation:"dd MMM yyyy" }}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-date-location-pipe-qeeanm?file=src/app/date-location.pipe.ts)

#### Update: Ignore UTC Time Offset

You could perform one more `split` over the `+` sign and ignore the time offset of the time stamp.

Pipe

```js
return super.transform(
    date[0].split('+')[0], 
    format, 
    timezone, 
    locale
  ) + 
  ' (' + 
  date[1].replace(/\]/g, ')');
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-date-location-pipe-wvzszf?file=src/app/date-location.pipe.ts)

Comment: Great solution, but seems the time is not correct when using the format dd MMM yyyy HH:mm. This prints some other time. Not the value provided in the ISO Zone Date Time String. Can you please comment on this?

Comment: @Klaus: There is an [UTC time offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) in the time stamp. So the time is calculated accordingly. What time do you expect to be shown?

Comment: The same time in the input string. For example If the input string is 2020-01-15T10:45:20+02:30[US/Denver]. Then my expected output is 01 Jan 2020 10:45:20 (US/Denver). Just the output of input values as it is according to the formatter without any date/time conversions or manipulations

Comment: @Klaus: You could then perform one more split on the timestamp over the `+` sign and ignore the offset. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great thanks. Now this works as expected. Can you please let me know what was causing the issue and how your fix solved it. I am new to angular and typescript

Comment: @Klaus: It isn't an issue. That is how Javascript Date object works. You could find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date